# Need to change the text in an image button

Tags: asp.net, css, image

I am having an image button as I have attached here. The respective code I use for this image button is

```
 <asp:ImageButton  ID="imgbtn_GenerateRpt" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/report.gif" Enabled="false"  CssClass="imageButton" 
                    onclick="imgbtn_GenerateRpt_Click"/>
```

css class

```
.imageButton![enter image description here][1]
      {
         position:relative;
         top:5px;![enter image description here][2]

      }
```

The text within this image button is "Generate Report".  I want a custom text "Acknowledge" to appear inside this image button instead of "generate Report" text.

How can i achieve this without using any image editing tools like photoshop or coreldraw?

Any help on this?

Comment: I'm not completely sure I understand what you're asking. Is the text you're referring to a part of the image, report.gif, file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image itself has text in it, then **there really isn't any way around creating a brand new image**.

Depending on the shape of the image you could possibly overlay a **`<div>`** element with its background color set the same as the image, but at that point you would simply be wasting your time.

[Download Paint.Net for free](http://paint.net/) and spend about 5 minutes creating a new image.